# CSS direto na tag HTML

Tags: css, html5

Trago uma dúvida hoje referente a CSS

As vezes sai mais viável colocar o código CSS direto na tag HTML e me pergunto se isso é uma prática ruim

Como prossigo com essa dúvida? é ruim mesmo? faço na hora e depois passo pra uma folha externa?

Agradeço

Comment: Depende do contexto. Se é um CSS que só vai ser usado naquela página, não tem problema nenhum. Economiza uma requisição inclusive. Se for para várias páginas, separado você tem o benefício do cache, e do reaproveitamento. Em situações pontuais dá pra por o CSS no próprio elemento também. O importante é conhecer os prós e os contras. Esse é o tipo de coisa que quando a pessoa só faz de um único jeito, ou não entende do assunto (o tal do seguidor de boas práticas), ou não trabalha de verdade com isso a ponto de só ter feito coisas muito elementares. Não tem como cortar caminho, tem que entender.

Comment: Eu não entendi bem se a pergunta é sobre CSS em tags `<style>`, sobre o atributo `style`, ou ambos.

Comment: É referente aos atributos style

Answer (score 2):

Isso é relativo a quantidade de código que você vai inserir, se você tem um CSS que cuide do design da página inteira é melhor deixar ele inteiro em um arquivo minificado e carregá-lo nas suas páginas. Mas suponhamos em uma página específica você não queira utilizar todo o arquivo, e quer só alguma classe ou algum ID específico desse CSS, para esse caso é melhor para a perfomance do seu site você inserir diretamente no HTML essas respectivas classes e Ids.

Comment: Concordo com você, estou tentando adquirir o máximo de boas práticas em todo os códigos que eu vá fazer. Tem algum site explicativo pra indicar?

Comment: Encontrei essas informações quando estava ouvindo esse [podcast](http://hipsters.tech/css-cansei-de-ser-simples-hipsters-09/)

Answer (score 2):

Eu diria que o ideal é evitar quando possível. A tal "boa prática" é como em outras ferramenta: não usamos o martelo para cortar ou o alicate para bater prego. Pra isso temos a folha de estilos, mantendo a organização.

Mas como já disseram, O inline, dependendo do caso, pode ser útil e até inevitável. Vale lembrar que ele tem precedência sobre estilos da folha (exceto os !important). Pode ser o último recurso, mesmo que não ideal, pra um design problemático, e aí eu uso sem dó mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Depende, se o estilo que você vai atribuir pode ser reutilizada de alguma maneira por outro componente, o ideal é que você separe em outro arquivo, porem se você tem intencionalmente quer que aquele estilo seja utilizado apenas para esse componente especifico ou apenas para uma pagina especifica, nesse caso o ideal é colocar o estilo apenas na pagina ou até mesmo diretamente no componente.